# Remove half corner bead

Tags: drywall, corner-bead

I’m replacing a portion of drywall that was previously covered in tile. The drywall is damaged enough that it needs replaced, not simply repairing.

The wall is 8’ and all tile was below the 4’ mark. My thought was to cut at the 4’ mark and replace that but I will run into corner beads and needed advice.

Is there an easy way to cut an already hung corner bead so I don’t have to replace/remud/repair the entire wall? Should I be thinking about this another way? Thank you for any thoughts/advice.

Comment: I have successfully removed the nails from a half of one side of a corner bead and removed the drywall and replaced it, then re-secured the drywall bead and refinished the wall with a lot less finish painting to do.

Comment: Hacksaw... cut gently with thumb/forefinger on the upper bead and you aren't likely to upset the remaining corner bead.